# One more incorrect LQA review?

Tags: support, disputed-review-audits, spam, low-quality-answers

I have a question about [this LQA review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/34880231). [Link to image for <10K rep](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ADQiG.png)

I believe the question itself should be closed as seeking recommendations. But since it was not at the moment of the answer, I don't think that author of the answer should be punished by deletion of their answer by a moderator, even less so through a red flag.

I don't think it is spam at all: it's a link to an application on Atlassian's Marketplace. The app is by a Gold member there (whatever this means, but it seems like Atlassian trusts them), and there isn't any obvious relation between the poster and the linked app. But maybe I'm missing something here.

Can somebody, please, look into this review and explain what I am missing and why it's a spam, or remove that answer from the review pool?

And if this review is in fact erroneous, can moderators review the deletion of that answer through the flag, so that answer's author is not punished for without a good reason?

Comment: When you see an answer that's basically a link+recommendation for a product, and you find it in the review queue, it really doesn't make you suspicious at all?

Comment: @yivi, when question asks for this recommendation (and some significant time between question and answer passed) - no.

Comment: Well, you need to be a bit more suspicious if you are going to spend time reviewing. Otherwise, just click "skip". And why would it matter that the Q and A weren't posted at the same time? Answer-only spam exists as well.

Comment: When you titled this Meta question "One more incorrect LQA review?", were you aware of the question about LQA review from just the other day, in which OP had the same question, about the same sort of post, which is considered spam for all the same reasons?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel, no. And before VLAZ's answer I truly did not understand reason behind result of that review.

Comment: I see spam as a side note here. The answer is a link and zero information on how to use whatever's at the link. That's not an answer that "looks OK."

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The plugin is by a company called Move Work Forward:

[image: Azure DevOps for Jira by Move Work Forward]

Somebody with (essentially) the same name and definitely the same avatar as the user "Tanya Bohutska" seems to work for a company called Move Work Forward, [according to LinkedIn](https://sg.linkedin.com/company/moveworkforward):

[image: "Tetiana Bohutska" listed as employee for Move Work Forward]

Answer (score 11):

The answer just consists of an external link and nothing more.  In the LQA queue you should be choosing one of the "delete" options, regardless of the spam flag.  The review action seems very clear to me and this seems like a fine audit.

I do somewhat regularly vote to close bad questions that have gotten bad answers; but that doesn't on its own excuse the bad answer.

Is this spam?  The layout of the answer – "did you find a solution?  If you try [enter link description here] then it does X, Y, and Z", with no obvious connection to a question – feels like a very spammy answer to me, and I probably would in fact have flagged this.

Comment: The key thing here, I believe, is that even if it wasn't spam, it still wasn't an OK post. Just because the question asks for recommendations doesn't mean we should be accepting answers that oblige. At the very least, if there is a problem with an answer due to the question it was posted, I'd hope the result is a Skip + an appropriate action on the question (e.g., close vote in this case).